# Selecting text file then reading its contents in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I was having a problem with pasting huge amount of text in a text area in HTML as it causes delays and slow processing time. Then one of the responders here in Stackoverflow suggested I upload the text file instead.

Now I am having problems on just how to do that exactly. I've been researching for hours but couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. What I need is for the user to select the text file then PHP reads the contents of that file into a variable. The file contains server logs so it should be huge.

I've been researching and options like fopen() or file_get_contents() seem to only open specific files, I need it dynamic, the user must select the file himself. Also, I am confused if I want to upload the file into the server or just read it's contents without uploading. I maybe prefer just reading.

We run a team that checks the user log of any users having issues, we have a tool that downloads a text file of any selected user, we then need to read that log into our PHP website/tool.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, still reading and analyzing it though. http://php-dev-zone.blogspot.com/2013/10/reading-and-displaying-content-of-text.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for, on the client side, is `<input type="file" name="myfile">` which allows the user to browse for a file - of any type - and upload it to the server. After it's uploaded, you get access to it from PHP through the `$_FILES` structure. See more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: Thanks, will read this too. So there's no other way to jsut read without uploading to server? I'm worried about too much files uploaded to the server

Comment: Not easily. There are workarounds, like plugins, ActiveX etc. But PHP runs on the server, and if you plan on using PHP to parse the file, you need to get it there.

Comment: Thanks, in my form I added <input type="file" name="fileupload"> then on the PHP action page I added the code echo file_get_contents($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name']); and it seem to print the contents. I also read that it is temporarily uploaded to the server and it will disappear unless I use a code to save it in a permanent location on the server which I do not want.:)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Store this result into one variable. Print this result. Check what will be shown.

But the condition is you should use html form. I think you know this basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks much, will try this as well, this looks easier and simple

Comment: Thanks, I used a combination of your suggestion and Traveling tech guy's but I couldn't upvote you both or check you both :s